# $ d(x_n,y_n) \to d(x,y)$ if $x_n\to x$ and $y_n \to y$

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Suppose that $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$. Is it true that
$$
d(x_n,y_n) \to d(x,y)?
$$

Comment: Hint: what does $x_n \to x$ actually mean?

Comment: Isn't this just triangle inequality?

Comment: Yeah. By using a quadrilateral inequality $d(x_n,y_n)\le d(x,y)+d(x_n,x)+d(y_n,y)$ and $d(x,y)\le d(x_n,y_n)+d(x_n,x)+d(y_n,y)$ :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $d(x_{n},y_{n})$ is bounded by some $d(x,y) + o(1)$ from above and some $d(x,y) + o(1)$ from below, then we are done. A useful upper bound is easy as by triangle inequality we have 
$$
d(x_{n},y_{n}) \leq d(x_{n},x) + d(x,y) + d(y,y_{n}).
$$
A useful lower bound can be obtained again by triangle inequality:
$$
d(x,y) \leq d(x_{n},x) + d(x_{n},y_{n}) + d(y_{n},y);
$$
i.e.
$$
d(x,y) - d(x_{n},x) - d(y_{n},y) \leq d(x_{n},y_{n}).
$$
Now as $n \to \infty$ we have
$$
d(x_{n},y_{n}) \to d(x,y).
$$